# What does "types" field do in package.json?

Tags: node.js, typescript, package.json

```json
{
  "files": [],
  "types": "./index.d.ts"
}
```

My understanding of `"files"` field is "including files in the array when the package is published to npm registry.

But I don't understand what `"types"` do here.

Comment: LMGTFY https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/publishing.html

Comment: @liam ok thanks man! I checked it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [typescript handbook:](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/publishing.html#including-declarations-in-your-npm-package)

> Set the types property to point to your bundled declaration file.

This key points to the `.d.ts` file for the typings when you publish a typescript package.

Comment: Can this answer be expanded to include the new export mapping too? You can put `types` in each map too.